# blank screen after suspend/hibernate on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, display, hibernate

My desktop always shows blank screen after suspend, while audio and other functionality is fine.
Strangely, when I hibernate my desktop, it would be succeed first time.
Second time, that is, hibernate again, sometimes shows blank screen, sometimes shows some blinking color bars on my screen. (https://youtu.be/FaLFJgBT_dQ)

Here's my desktop OS information:

```
Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Linux kernel version: 4.4.0-139-generic
```

And Here's my hardware information:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Motherboard: ASUS B360M-A

No other external video card, just integrated video card.
```